# Is the preimage of a bounded set also bounded?

Tags: inverse

I need to prove the following statement:

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a continuous function and $B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ bounded, implies, that the set $A=f^{-1}(B)$ to be bounded.

I do know that the statement is true for a continuous function on closed sets.

**Is it possible, that this statement is also true for just bounded sets; and if not, what is the argumentation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider constant function $f(z)=c$ for all $z$, then $\{c\}$ is bounded, but $f^{-1}(\{c\})=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So in case my set $B$ is closed the statement is true.

Comment: Just to get it right:

A bounded image does not imply, that the preimage must be bounded.

Comment: What about the fact, that a constant function has no inverse function?

Comment: Yes, a bounded image doesn't imply that preimage is bounded. But what do you mean with inverse function? Do you want to know that if $f$ has an inverse function your statement is true?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking about.

Answer (score 3):

For a nonconstant (in fact injective) counterexample, since you're not requiring $f$ to be differentiable, you can just do something like
$$ f(z) = \frac{z}{1+|z|} $$
which is a continuous function on a closed set (namely, all of $\mathbb C$). The preimage of the open unit disc is then all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think get closer now!

Comment: @PhoemueX: That is still not injective: You get $f(\frac12)=f(2)=\frac 25$. On the other hand $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ would work, if the tanh offends you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ok, maybe I should stop thinking about math for tonight. Thank you very much!